# MUFG Interest/Duplication Rates

Tags: ingress

I had 6 VRHS inside my MUFG and a new one was created in under 24 hours. I also had 4 ADA's and 4 Jarvis's that weren't touched.

So my question is how do the duplication rates get determined? Is it by item type, number of items or random chance?

<sub>Official data is always nice.</sub>

Comment: Considering that MUFG have been put in game only 5 days ago, it may be too soon to have relevant data. I highly doubt we'll get any official data too, considering how secretive Niantic has always been about the inner workings of Ingress. That said, [this guy](https://plus.google.com/+JoshuaSmithjdthyme/posts) is reporting his daily findings with his MUFG, so you may get interesting data from there.

Comment: Cold hard speculation is always nice. Asking early is equally nice.

Comment: I can definitely tell you that duping appears to be completely random.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thanks to the tireless effort of the Ingress community we actually have a solid(ish) answer to the question. As described [here, full kudos to everyone who helped](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+PetrMor%C3%A1vek/posts/SKnUoW7H1qh)

1. Duplication rates do not vary among different types of items.
2. All capsules of a player trigger one duplication event per day at a random time. All capsules duplicate at the same time. At the moment we are not sure when the exact time is, but an educated guess says 00:00 UTC.
3. Unloading the MUFG capsule doesn't affect duplication, the only thing that matters is the contents of the capsule at the specified duplication time.
4. Every item in the cap has a approximately a 1-1.5% chance of duplicating itself.

This means that:

1. If your capsule has already had its duplication event for the day, you can safely unload it.
2. The optimal load for an MUFG is <strike>95</strike>96 items.
3. Assuming the capsule is optimally loaded you should get (on average) 1 duplicated item per day.

Again full credit goes to Petr Morávek, I've only reproduced his findings here, to prevent a link only answer.

### Update:

There's been some discussion on Reddit about this, and then some hard data collected by <strike>totally obsessed</strike> dedicated agents that discuss tactics about MUFG loadout, but it comes down to how frequently you can check your MUFG for duplication. The reddit post in question can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/3munw1/optimal_mufg_configuration_details_in_comments) but it basically says the following:

1. Optimal loadout is 96 items [(based on math)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14mmeY0SheYP-L3h0Nztoig01PIqtAh6dkg9a0f7KSQU/edit#gid=555945242)<sup><sup>See update below</sup></sup>
2. If you have more than 97 items, consider splitting the load between 2 MUFG's to avoid filling it when duplicating
3. If you can't check your MUFG every day, fill it with 90 items and check once a week.
4. If you're leaving your items with an inactive friend, fill it with 75 items and check  back in a month.

### Update 2:

If your capsule is storing Very Rare gear, then the optimal number of items is 98 even if you are checking your capsules every day. This is due to the reduction in duplication rates for VR gear put in place a month ago. This is only if you're breeding VR gear, this doesn't apply if you're breeding common or rare gear.

Comment: It seems duplication rate may now be tied to item rarity, starting around Feb. 19, 2016: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/477xt8/mufg_interest_rates_may_be_tied_to_item_rarity_now/

Comment: Something to note after all these years, is that very rare items no longer duplicate in Ingress Prime, so Update 2 in above post no longer applies.

Answer (score -3):

As I have been led to understand it, the duplication process is random. What I was told could be wrong on that one though. What I do know is that there is a timer on the MUFG that resets every time you open it and look inside.

Duplication occurs somewhere in between ~5 hours and 5 days.  Keep an eye out on your item count inside of the capsule and only load new things in there when you notice that duplication has already occurred.